# Getting " type of namespace definition, or end-of-file expected error"

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace test

{
    public class multiplying
    {   
        public static void Main( string[] args);
        { //getting invalid '{' token here 
            int number1;
            int number2;
            int total;

        }
    }
} // getting type of namespace definition, or end-of-file expected error here
```

The programme isn't finished obviously but when I write more in I just get more errors so there must be something wrong here but I don't know what.

Comment: Ex Delphi programmer, right? ;-) I keep making this mistake in other languages.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void Main( string[] args);
```

should be

```
public static void Main( string[] args)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra semi-colon here :
public static void Main( string[] args);

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void Main( string[] args);
```

You have an extra `;` there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that familiar with C#, but I think this is your problem:

```
    public static void Main( string[] args);
    { //getting invalid '{' token here
```

`;` is ending the declaration, so the `{` is considered completely separate (and don't make sense without a function signature coming first. Try changing it to this:

```
    public static void Main( string[] args)
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a ; after the closing bracket of the argument list.